# Recursive copy directories

Tags: php, recursion, directory, copy

I have a function for recursive copy directories. But I'm getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/temp/install_5630013a79723/site, /temp/install_5630013a79723/site): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)'

public static function copyDir($source, $dest) {

            @mkdir($dest, 0755);
            foreach ($iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),  \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
              if ($item->isDir()) {
                @mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
              } else {
                @copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
              }
            }
        }
```

How can I fix/improve my function?

Comment: It would seem that the constructor for a RecursiveDirectoryIterator is throwing an exception.  Based on the message passed in the exception, it probably can't find a file, but this is pure speculation as you haven't included the code for the constructor, where the actual exception is being thrown. -- As for how to improve your function, run this command at the terminal: `man cp`